# Search MySQL database with unknown column content

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I need to extract multiple rows that are associated with each while not knowing which are.

Say I have three columns

```
ID     |  Start    |   End
---------------------------
1      |    A      |    B
2      |    B      |    C
3      |    B      |    D
4      |    C      |    D
5      |    C      |    A
```

I want to exact all the rows that build a graph from A to D.

But I don't know the intermediate letters between A and D or I know it has to pass by C (which in this case would be ID 1,2,4 and not 1,3).

Is there a way to do this without going to a full blown graph database? (I will at a later stage, but for now I'm stuck with MySQL)

Comment: In MySQL, you can do this with a recursive stored procedure.